# Is there an off the shelf CMS that can be used as a back end for smartphone travel guide apps?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, content-management-system, smartphone

I'm wondering if there's an off the shelf CMS available that is similar to something like Mobile Roadie - ie: it will allow you to create multiple versions of one application? I'm looking to develop some mobile travel guides for iPhone/Android/Blackberry etc, and rather than get a CMS built, I'd like to see if there's something out there is similar to Wordpress in that it will allow us to input text, images, Google Maps details, phone numbers, email addresses and potentially some audio/video content.

If anyone knows of anything, I'd love to hear about it. Also, if you have any ideas regarding pricing, that would be extremely helpful! Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: This isn't programming related, but is a question about software packages, so it belongs on Super User.

Comment: Agreed. This is product review request.

Answer (score 0):

The chances of you finding something "Off the shelf" diminish as your requirements get more specific. You want something for a limited and specific target audience (iPhone, Andriod, Blackberry) that can deliver many different types of very specific content (addresses, maps, text, images, video).

From my experience of building a CMS for one of the world's most famous travel guides, I can say your chances are slim indeed. The technical requirements of managing this type of information are huuuuuge!

But hell, I could be wrong! I hope you find something that solves your problem and you make the world a better place!

PS: Maybe you should simplify your requirements and build from there? Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just dropped a reply on this question:
[How to setup a CMS as a backend for iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856370/how-to-setup-a-cms-as-a-backend-for-iphone-app/)

You could look at this blog for a drupal showcase:
http://drupal.org/node/900630

and at this wordpress plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/

Personally I am trying with tikiwiki.org but I am not sure yet if it is right.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

We created a very flexible CMS called [StorageRoom](http://storageroomapp.com) which we built specifically for mobile apps.

You could easily let users manage locations with maps and additional fields.