# How to setup a CMS as a backend for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, content-management-system, backend

I would like my iPhone app to get dynamic content off the net. This content should be managed using a CMS. I would like to know in particular if I can setup Drupal or Joomla or other CMS as a backend for my iphone app to get the content.

Any advice on how this can be achieved would be helpful.

I am completely new to setting up/using CMS.

Comment: Although this is not the solution I'm looking for, this is a great article about simple backend setup for complete newbies  (like me) http://www.cimgf.com/2010/02/12/accessing-the-cloud-from-cocoa-touch/

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look at [StorageRoom](http://storageroomapp.com), which is a CMS for Mobile Applications.

Disclaimer: I created this myself to scratch my own itch.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress with the [JSON-API plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) is a great solution, especially if you need a web site as well.

You can find a good example [here](http://alexbachuk.com/wordpress-and-phonegap-part-1/) that uses Wordpress and Phonegap to get a basic app going.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the content in any serialized format (e.g. XML or JSON), it should be no problem to use any CMS as a "backend" for your application.

Comment: does drupal or joomla provide such a feature of providing the content in XML/JSON? and also authenticating each request to the server? or should i implement these features on my own in the server?

Comment: A Google search for `drupal json` looks positive, as does `drupal authenticate request`, @srik ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm checking out storageroom, and I'm searching for a similar answer, but I also found osmek to be a bit promising. I might use that one because of the menu templates .Osmek can provide responses in json and xml (and other formats that aren't useful in iphone dev like php, html, and templates)

Answer (score 1):

Feed.Us is another option.  I have a series of travel guides iphone apps and use Feed.Us to manage the businesses listed within the apps.

It creates a URL with XML that gets imported into the app.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a very promising solution!

[Apache Usergrid](http://usergrid.incubator.apache.org)

I have briefly tried [DreamFactory](https://www.dreamfactory.com) for some trial project but never got around to using it in production. Usergrid seems to be in the right direction in providing a full fledged solution (which can also work for modern web apps)

Answer (score 0):

I'm very curious about Helios ([helios.io](http://helios.io)) and will be trying it out shortly. 
At least from the write-up on their site it looks very promising. Its open source, and in beta currently. They also have very easy heroku hosting support.

> Helios is an open-source framework that provides essential backend
>   services for iOS apps, from data synchronization and push
>   notifications to in-app purchases and passbook integration.

I will update the answer again once I use this for some test project.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any cms or framework to implement this. you need to make a jsonm api to communicate between app and backend server.

For php cms joomla, drupal and wordpress are best.
in frameworks you can use yii, cakephp, laravel or zend

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Also worth taking a look at Cloud CMS:
http://www.cloudcms.com

It's a cloud content management system for mobile and web applications, entirely oriented around JSON and having a fast, fully featured API.  Your iOS application could easily grab things, render them, capture data, store it back into the CMS and more.  Plus, it gives you a user interface you can drop in front of your business users so that they can create, edit and review things.

Note: I'm one of the developers.  That said, worth checking out if for no other reason than for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data-complexity, perhaps willing a CMS into being a data-store or simple API is overkill when you can leverage file storage services like [Google Drive/Apps](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/) to GET/POST spreadsheets or other documents in JSON, among other formats.

[Is it possible to use Dropbox, Google Drive, Skydrive, etc. as a server space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14259613/1105203)