# Is it possible to use Dropbox, Google Drive, Skydrive, etc. as a server space?

Tags: android, ios, cloud, storage

I'm creating an app that connects online to a server to collect information. To save money from renting server space from a big corp, I was wondering if any of these free services (Dropbox, Google Drive, Microsoft Skydrive, Amazon Cloud, etc.) could be potentially used as server space?

I pretty much want a "space" or "cloud" where people can connect to to collect data. Example: I have a weather app, and there is files on my server and I update the files according to the weather. I would like them to be able to open the app and connect to my server to gather the weather data saved on my server. It really won't be much digital space, so I didn't want to pay bookoo bucks when I could potentially use a free service like Dropbox.

Comment: @SimonSchubert lol, Thanks! Do you where I could find information to find out how to do this?

Comment: @RobAveryIV Did you ever get this working? I'm trying something similar just what to see what other people went with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't execute remote code on any of those services (that I'm aware of), but you could certainly save files to them.  For example, you could write out text files (CSV?  XML?  JSON?) to those locations.

Take a look at the [Dropbox SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/setup#ios) for details on how to integrate it to your iOS or Android project.  It's pretty simple.

Here's a basic code sample for uploading a file:

```
NSString *localPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
NSString *filename = @"Info.plist";
NSString *destDir = @"/";
[[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
```

Answer (score 2):

I heard several times that it's working, but hadn't made my own experience yet.

Check out this post http://lifehacker.com/5528104/use-dropbox-to-share-and-host-your-web-site

As Axeva said you can't run your own scripts or sql. You have to write your own workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can use Dropbox. But only if you want to download or upload some files. And I'm not sure if it's ideal. But there are other alternatives you may want to look at. Like you can use GoogleAppEngine if you want some processing to be done on server. Maybe Parse.com is another choice but not sure if it fits your needs.

Comment: Pretty much I want some "space" or "cloud" where I can save information to that people (who use my app) can connect collect this information.

Comment: In that case Dropbox would be great. But there are some bandwidth limits on how much you can download per day. Usually it's always quite high and you will not have to worry about it.

Comment: Just read your update on question. You have nothing to worry about bandwidth limits :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [site44](http://site44.com/). It allows you to connect with dropbox and use a friendly URL (own domain or otherwise) for accessing the files.

Comment: That looks pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using something like Parse.com as your backend. Their free tier lets you store 1GB. Maybe not as much as Dropbox, but the API for Parse is great and made for storing/retrieving from mobile apps. You'll be up and running really fast. I haven't looked at Dropbox SDK though.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox works fine if all you want to do is using it as an FTP to put some JSON or XML files on.

Just be sure to put it in your dropbox's 'public' folder and requesting the public link.